# Why does ruby 2.4.0 always try to install when i enter this directory?

Tags: ruby, terminal

Every time I enter into this specific directory, I get a message that ruby-2.4.0 is not installed. I'm wondering if I set something to run a command when I enter this directory, but I'm having trouble locating where it may be doing this so that I can not have it run anything when i go into this folder.

```
% cd omnibus
Required ruby-2.4.0 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install "ruby-2.4.0"'
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow!  When you have code or shell output to share, it's usually better to just post it inside the text of your question instead of linking to an image on external site.  I'll go ahead and edit your question so you can see how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have [RVM](https://rvm.io/) installed on that machine.  RVM adds a hook to your shell that detects when you change into a directory with a configuration file specifying what Ruby version to use.

You can run `ls -la` in your `omnibus` directory to look for that configuration file.  It is probably named `.ruby-version`.